# Allow a method to be invoked based on the version of Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

A method call I want to invoke is only available for Windows Phone 8 and not for the earlier versions, but I want to keep supporting the app for WP8 as well as WP7.1.

I don't mind having a fallback if the device doesn't have WP8.

Is it possible to instruct the app to conditionally invoke the method, and also remove the compile time error.

To achieve something like this on Android (let's say to support pre Froyo devices), what one could do is wrap the piece of code with `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)` to avoid the compile time check and before invoking the required method explicitly check for the android version

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR_MR1)
```

Possible to do something like this on Windows Phone?

+++++++++++++++++

UPDATE:
Tried to use reflection but failed so I am describing the exact problem.

Actually, I want to call `GetHostNames()` from [NetworkInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.aspx)

Now since the app targets WP7.1 and WP8 I seem to be unable to reference the namespace with

`using Windows.Networking.Connectivity;`

because the corresponding assembly isn't referenced (I think). I tried, but couldn't find which assembly is this namespace part of.

Without having a working reference to the namespace, my guess is even reflection won't work.

Please excuse me if I am making a beginner mistake, I am new to Windows Phone as well as C# but loving the environment so coming here seeking some knowledge!

Comment: Have you tried using reflection to invoke the method?

Comment: Ahh, ignorant me. Thanks for the pointer @Jon. Will try to get it working by using reflection. BTW, not that I've something against reflection, but still just wondering, is there an approach similar to the way Android-sdk allows supporting older versions. Isn't the android approach cleaner than the reflection alternative?

Comment: I'd go for conditional compilation. If you want to properly support WP8, you have to convert your project to WP8 (otherwise, the app won't use the full screen on 720p resolutions). Here are some tricks to help maintain a WP7 and WP8 of a same app: http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Maintaining_a_WP7_and_WP8_version_of_a_same_Silverlight_application

Comment: @JonSkeet: Updated the question, please take a look.

Answer (score 3):

To propert support both platforms you should maintain two identical projects, referencing the same code files, but targeting different framework versions. And when doing that, you can then do the following:

Open your application `.csproj` file, and change the `<DefineConstants>` element into the following two lines:

```
<DefineConstants Condition=" $(TargetFrameworkVersion) == 'v7.1' ">DEBUG;TRACE;SILVERLIGHT;WINDOWS_PHONE;WP7</DefineConstants>
<DefineConstants Condition=" $(TargetFrameworkVersion) == 'v8.0' ">DEBUG;TRACE;SILVERLIGHT;WINDOWS_PHONE;WP8</DefineConstants>
```

You'll need to apply this to both the debug and release configurations.

Then wrap your WP8 specific code in a [preprocessor directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4y6tbswk.aspx), like:

```
#if WP8
    using Windows.Networking.Connectivity;
#endif
```

Finally the build conditionals can also be applied to assembly reference include statements, example:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile, Version=6.2.959.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" Condition=" $(TargetFrameworkVersion) == 'v8.0' " />
</ItemGroup>
```